# How load Digital Elevation Model (DEM) file with Open CV

Tags: java, opencv, raster

I am trying to convert the great tutorial [Reading Geospatial Raster files with GDAL](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/highgui/raster-gdal/raster_io_gdal.html?highlight=imread) from Open CV C++ to Open CV Java API.

My problem: when I load DEM file using:
`Mat dem = Imgcodecs.imread(demFile.htg, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL | Imgcodecs.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);`

I found that `dem.type()` is not  equal to CV_16SC1 as expected but equal to CV_8U.

Is this a problem? May it depend on the specific .htg file that I am currently using ?

Answer (score 0):

Now I can answer myself. The problem is with GDAL support, which is not enabled by default into OpenCV.

When I added this kind of support, DEM image was correctly load.